# Office365 outlook mail HTML email render

Tags: html, outlook, html-email

I am using office365 email at my workplace to access emails. I am required to generate a dynamic newsletter which will be developed in HTML, However, I cannot seem to figure out how to add that HTML page into the email, pasting plain HTML doesn't seem to work as outlook does not render that.

I found a work around after some research, which is to open the html page on a browser, simply copy the content using CTRL + A and paste onto email editor, that seems to add the html but this is not a proper solution!

The aim is to write HTML, (Have done that) and add the HTML page into the outlook email. Any help/suggestion is highly appreciated

Comment: Do you write HTML directly inside email client or are you using some programming language to generate that HTML?

Comment: I simply write the HTML on an HTML editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both email clients and web browsers can display HTML/CSS, but they have different ways of doing so. So if you copy/paste an HTML page, chances are it will not display the same way in an email client like Outlook365.

Email layouts need to use `<table>`s for layout instead of `<div>`s. Emails also only support [a small of CSS rules](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) that need to be inlined.

Email code looks more like this:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" style="vertical-align: top;background: #aaaaaa;">
      <span style="color: red; font-size: 12px;">text</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" style="vertical-align: top;">
      <img src="full path to image" alt="alt text" width="50" height="50">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you rebuild your email like this, it should display better in email clients like Outlook365.

Comment: The point is, outlook365 email editor does not render HTML, it simply shows the plain HTML on both the sender and receiver mail even after setting the format to HTML instead of plain text.

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure there is a way to send styled HTML email using Office365 mail only. You may be limited to text-only or 'rich text'. Is using a third party ESP to send email to your workplace's email addresses an option?

Comment: Not really, I am only allowed to use outlook online

Comment: I think you may be relegated to office365 rich text and the HTML it produces (similar to the 'HTML' that MS Word produces when you do layouts in Word).

Answer (score 1):

First of all please look at [this](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) list of supported CSS in various email clients.

Than make sure you also have CSS inside email. Best way is using inline CSS:

```
<div style="color: red; font-size: 12px;">HALO!</div>
```

---

When pasting make sure you are pasting it as HTML (don't know if you can do it in all email clients). Otherwise it will encode your pasted text and sending it will expose all HTML markup as text.

Comment: Yeah the problem remains, Outlook does not Render this line even after I have selected mail format as HTML.